# My leopard gecko won't shed

Tags: reptiles, leopard-geckos, geckos, shedding

My leopard gecko has only shed once and I got him on May 19th, 2018.

Sometimes he goes pale but nothing happens, he always has wet moss, I give him baths. He seems healthy, there's nothing wrong with him, he's active, eats perfectly fine and has calcium powder in the tank which he eats from time to time. I just want to know what can I do to help him shed because I tried everything that I know of.
[image]

Comment: My leopard gecko hasn't she'd ever since I've gotten him which was multiple months ago I check on him at least every other day but I've never even seen him pre shed

Answer (score 4):

Leopard Geckos shed throughout their entire lives, the reason you do not see the shed is because they [eat it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ttFqNMk57g)! Once full grown they shed less regularly (this varies from species to species).

Healthy geckos will have their full shed within 24 hours, it is always a good idea to regularly check their extremities to ensure that there is no remaining shed.

Comment: I know that they eat. He did finally shed a couple months ago cuz I put him in a warm bath full of moss more frequent and it came off in one peace but yeah I think he  the shed less because he's fully grown thank you for responding and for the help , sorry that I'm late didn't know anybody responded

Answer (score 0):

He/she looks to be full grown.

If you give him/her a bath regularly and have moist moss in there and it isn’t shedding it is likely full grown.

Enjoy your gecko!